# How to save pointer to last node

Tags: c, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

Here I have a delete by position function for doubly linked lists. I am trying to save a pointer to the last node so that when printing in reverse direction, I do not have to iterate to last node.

```
node* deleteByPos(node* list, node** last, int position) {
    int c = 0;
    node* temp;
    node* prev;

    temp=list;
    if (temp==NULL) {
        printf("No nodes available to delete\n\n");
        return list;
    } else {
        while(temp!=NULL && c != position) {
            prev=temp;
            temp=temp->next;
            c++;
        }
        if (temp==NULL) {
            printf("Reached end of list, position not available\n\n");
            return list;
        } else if (temp->next == NULL) {
            prev->next=temp->next;
            temp->next->prev = prev;
            &last = temp->next;
            free(temp);
            return list;
        } else {
            prev->next=temp->next;
            temp->next->prev = prev;
            free(temp);
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to delete the last position in the list, I get a segmentation fault. How do I fix?

Comment: Did you trying running a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) and stepping through it?

Comment: Saving a `tail` pointer is a principal advantage of a doubly-linked list for the very purpose of allowing reverse iteration. In a non-circular list you will generally keep two pointers `head` and `tail` to the beginning and end nodes, respectively. In a *circular* list, `head->prev` points to the last node, and `head->prev->next` points to `head`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your else block else if (tmp->next == NULL) you have a line

```
temp->next->prev = prev;
```

This is invalid.  You're trying to use the null pointer.

Comment: oh ok. this exposed some other bugs within the block